# How to repalce all html comments in Jsp file with html comments in eclipse

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

I have a requirement to replace all html comments in all jsp file in my work space with jsp comments. I need to search for all  and replace with <%-- --%> and I should not loose the comments.

For Eg

```
       <!-- I have a comment here --> should be replaced with.
       <%-- I have a comment here --%>
```

I am using eclipse to do this. Please let me know if I have some other better way to do it.

Comment: It is not regarding code issue, rather a code maintenance work

Comment: Ankur, I am trying to develop small app which does it.

Answer (score 0):

You could go through the file (line by line) and do something like this:

```
line.replaceAll("<!--","<%--"); //or line.replace("<!--","<%--");
line.replaceAll("-->","--%>"); //or line.replace("-->","--%>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perlish way:

Run this through your command line over the jsp folder

```
perl -pi -e 's/<!--/<%/g;s/-->/--%>/g' jspfolder/*
```